# How to watch variables in gsp while debugging?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am writing a Grails application, I am getting errors.

I have to debug my .gsp file, I have a variable like this ${itemId}. I want to watch this value. How can I do that? It not appearing in variables tab.

I added ${itemId} in expressions but no output.

Answer (score 1):

no efficient but you can use

```
<% println('${itemid}'); %>
```

inside your .gsp file . But make sure that the variable has been passed to the view form your controller or something like this. Don't forget to place a break point.

```
def testController() {
   .
   .
   .
   .
  //other codes here

 [itemid:yourmodel.id, //otherstuffs here]   
}
```

Comment: My situation is  very bad. that I have check lot of variables, i just mentioned only one. It is difficult to write statement for every thing. and some times it is not direct object, it is some collections  or custom objects.

Comment: @kumarM ok ,kumer ...did you use Display on your debug window ...if you use STS or Eclips based IDE ..try display and type the variable and then press run button the content will be displayed for you...i.e the variables..

Answer (score 0):

In your gsp you should be able to do something like this:

```
<div>
    ${params}
</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure how it works/what exactly it shows but it does seem to at least show all the params in the URL.

Hope it helps and if you figure out a better way, clue the rest of us in, please!